# How do I add a css file to the head block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.0

I'm building a Magento 2 module for learning purposes.
I'm trying to add a css file to all configurable product pages but I'm failing miserably.

Here is what I tried.
In `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout` I added this file: `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Magento/Core/etc/page.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="head">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Css" name="namespace-module-css">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module:css/styles.css</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

The layout file is taken into consideration but I get the following error in the console

> 403 Forbidden - ROOT/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Namespace_Module:css/styles.css

The file mentioned in the error message does not exist (it is not generated) even if the original file I'm trying to add exists in `/app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/css/styles.css`
If I remove the `Namespace_Module` prefix from the `<argument>` tag it includes a different `styles.css`. The one from `pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles.css`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run `php -f dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View/deploy.php`? I think something like this is necessary, so that files are deployed to `pub/static`...

Comment: I'm running on developer mode and all the caches are disabled. I don't think this is the issue. But I will try just to get it out of the way.

Comment: @Simon. Tried it. Other than a lot of errors listed in the console I got the same result. But I figured it out in the end. The problem was me. See my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about an outdated magento 2 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I'm a little embarrassed.
The problem was between my keyboard and my chair.
The separator for module name ad file is `::` not `:`.
I should be more careful.
So the correct way to do it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Magento/Core/etc/page.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="head">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Css" name="namespace-module-css">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::css/styles.css</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

I should delete this question as it may seam off topic.
But I will let it live as it may serve as learning material for others.

Comment: Isn't this out of date now? As far as I'm aware referenceblock name="head" is no longer the correct way to add a CSS file. It should now be <css src="Magento_Theme::css/styles.css /> within <head></head>

Comment: Yep. This is outdated now.

Comment: What happens when an answer is redundant, should I post an up to date answer or is the question closed?

Comment: Usually it is better to post am updated answer. But in this case the question should be closed sonce the code in the question os outdated.